# Gnome-panels take a long time to load on startup

Tags: gnome-panel

I am using the 64 bit of ubuntu maverick desktop. The problem is that as soon as I login, the wallpaper and the desktop icons appear almost instantly, however the panel-takes an eternity to load, sometimes as long as 30 secs. I have a fairly modern system, so I am sure this is software related. Any fixes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `top` say? Do you see any related error messages in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. .xsession-errors isn't especially interesting. Watching top -- use ctrl-alt-F3 (or anything but F7, actually) to access a shell -- shows a lot of stuff booting up. In my case, Munin uses a lot of resources (so I'm looking into disabling it). Liferea takes its sweet time (so I'm wondering if there's a way to throttle that) and Ubuntu-One is busy busy.

I see other programs as well, including Conky, but I do want them on startup so i don't see a way around that.

Comment: Thats exactly the point. Lots of things i do want to start immediately, eat a lot of cpu.

Comment: The first step, though, is to watch top to get a sense of what is eating CPU and make sure you want it.